# Transmission of helicobacter pylori

Tags: disease-transmission, sanitation, contaminate, helicobacter-pylori

I used spoon of my friend who had h pylori infection. Can it infect me. I shared her ice cream with the spoon that she was using.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could possibly become infected through sharing utensils.

https://publichealth.arizona.edu/outreach/health-literacy-awareness/hpylori/transmission

> **H. pylori is commonly transmitted person-to-person by saliva.** The
>   bacteria can also be spread by fecal contamination of food or water.
>   In developing countries, a combination of untreated water, crowded
>   conditions, and poor hygiene contributes to higher H. pylori
>   prevalence. Most people become infected as children, and parents and
>   siblings seem to play a primary role in transmission.

However, h. pylori is a common infection and there's about a [50% chance](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11218379) you were already infected before you shared the spoon. It causes no symptoms in most people, so this event wasn't something you need to run to a doctor about.